# Does a successful ssh, and a failed sshfs must imply a local error?

Tags: ssh, sshfs

I can successfully log on to a server via `ssh`.

```
ssh root@server_ip
```

However, trying to sshfs

```
sshfs root@server_ip:/home
```

gives an error:

```
remote host has disconnected
```

If `ssh` is passing on the server side does that mean that the failure of `sshfs` is on the local side?

In other words, does a successful `ssh` mean that it **must** be possible to `sshfs` on that same server (without changing anything on the server)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, **working ssh access does not imply a working sshfs.**

This is because sshfs relies on SFTP in the background, which must be allowed by the server. The default configuration shipped with the OpenSSH Server allows it though (that's why it works at most places), but the local Administrator can of course choose to disable it.

Furthermore, SFTP support and wether it is enabled/needs to be compiled in is dependent on the the SSH server (there are alternatives to OpenSSH).